# Make date format similiar in data set pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, jupyter-notebook

I want to make date format same for all the rows in date column. For example 19th row has diff date format. This is only part of data set. There are diff rows as well which have same kind of format. So what can I do to make all date format same in all rows?

I tried using

```
Covid_data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(Covid_data['date'], errors='coerce')
```

but it converts 19th row value into NAT

```
16  Australia   2020-01-16  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 44648.71    25499881.0  
17  Australia   2020-01-17  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 44648.71    25499881.0  
18  Australia   2020-01-18  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 44648.71    25499881.0  
19  Australia   2020-19-01  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 44648.71    25499881.0   
20  Australia   2020-01-20  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 44648.71    25499881.0  
21  Australia   2020-01-21  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 44648.71    25499881.0  
22  Australia   2020-01-22  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 44648.71    25499881.0
```

Comment: Yes.. that is because of inconsistent date formats.

Comment: that is what i want to do. make all date format same in all rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
Covid_data['date']=pd.to_datetime(Covid_data['date'].dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'))
```

edit: try this

Comment: Showing this error        AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: I have edited the solution. If it still doesn't work you may need to include: errors='coerce'.

Comment: Same Error                                                                                                                                             AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike value

Answer (score 0):

You could try making use of the `dateparser` package, but I wouldn't know how you intend to determine the appropriate format for dates like `2020-01-08`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import dateparser

covid_data = pd.DataFrame({"date" : ["2020-01-18", "2020-19-01"]})

covid_data["date"].apply(dateparser.parse)
```